# Get value of nth item in an un-ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

For this code,

```
<ul id="date-list" hidden="hidden">
<% foreach (string item in (List<string>)Model.OpenCloseTime)
   {%>
    <li value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></li>
<% }%>
</ul>
```

How could i get the value of nth item in the list. It is an MVC project and we are using jquery. 
Basically I am trying to use the string value as a min max time for an input of type="time".

Thanks!

Comment: LI elements don't have a `value` attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#date-list').children().eq(n).attr('value');
```

However, if you want a custom data attribute, html5 states you should precede it with `data-`

```
<li data-value="<%= item %>"><%= item %></li>

$('#date-list').children().eq(n).data('value');
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw afterwards that the value and text were the same, but the OP is asking for the `value` so it could go either way.

Comment: It works either way, but the `value` attribute is non-standard for LI elements, so one might want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 5):

```
var found = $('#date-list').find('li').eq(n).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$( '#date-list' ).children().eq( n ).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#date-list>li:nth-child('+n+')'.attr('value');
```